# Dealing with month abbreviations when converting to a date

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, data-cleaning

I'm trying to convert a column to a date and am having some trouble. The dates are a in a column named month and each value is an abbreviated month followed by a year, like "Nov 2016" and "Mar 2017". What's the best way to convert this column to a date so I can use it as the x-axis on a graph.

Thanks!

Comment: when you format a date you can use `format="%d %b"` to get the 3 letter abbreviation, `%B` is the full month name, `%m` is the numeric version. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue comes around a lot on Stack Overflow. Basically: month + year is not a date - you need a day too.

The usual solutions are (1) use `zoo::as.yearmon` to make a "year month" object:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon("Nov 2016", "%b %Y")
```

or (2) use the first of the month as an arbitrary day to create a date:

```
as.Date(paste("01", "Nov 2016"), "%d %b %Y")
```